# Formula to compute the average of calculated values using elements of an array, in VBA

Tags: vba, function, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula in VBA.

I have an array let's say [A,B,C,D].
I want a function to return the following formula =average(A/B,B/C,C/D)

I simplified this somewhat as my range will be quite long.
I need the formula to continue until the end of the range, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Load the values in a variant array.  Loop the variant array and load another variant array with the value divided by the item +1 from the current.  Then average the output variant array.

Comment: Now, I don't understand what `A,B,C,D` stand for. Consider this: Using `VBA` I want to write the following formula in column `E` starting from row 2 to the last row: `=AVERAGE(A2/B2,B2/C2,C2/D2)`. Could you explain the difference between the previous, and your question?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Scott's comment. This is the implementation:

EDIT: As suggested by Scott, no need to redim preserve

Line added: `ReDim resultValues(1 To UBound(sourceValues) - 1)`

```
Public Function CalcAvg(ByVal sourceRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim sourceValues As Variant
    sourceValues = Application.Transpose(sourceRange.Value)

    Dim resultValues() As Variant
    Dim counter As Long
    ReDim resultValues(1 To UBound(sourceValues) - 1)
    For counter = 1 To UBound(sourceValues) - 1
        
        resultValues(counter) = sourceValues(counter) / sourceValues(counter + 1)
    
    Next counter
    
    CalcAvg = Application.Average(resultValues)

End Function
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner